# How to group SQL output using Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

Suppose I have an output table like this:

```
Names |   Values
_______________
 A    |   value1
 A    |   value2
 B    |   value3
 B    |   value4
 C    |   value5
```

I use dapper to connect to the database. Instead of direct sql commands, I call a stored procedure that has multiple queries so I use `QueryMultipleAsync` to get the results but I got stuck on this one. For the sake of this example, the task returns only this one.

```
public async Task<Something> GetData()
{
    using (IDbConnection database = _mssqlDbConnectionFactory.Connect())
    {
        var results = await database.QueryMultipleAsync("spGetSomething");
        ...
        IEnumerable<Something> something = results.Read< > ...

        return something
    }
}

public class Something
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public List<string>? Values { get; set; }
}
```

Besides, I use sql server and the query for this output is kinda long, so I didn't include it here, and if I'm correct, there is no way of grouping them together, since I need every value.
What are my options here? Can I use some kind of linq to group them when I read the result?

Comment: Tell us what you want the result to be. Also show us the stored procedure because it's unclear how the "suppose I have output like" represents multiple query resultsets

Comment: *For the sake of this example, the task returns only this one.* - don't dumb anything down for us, you risk getting stuck because you can't translate the advice we give back to your situation. We can cope with full and accurate details - saying you're using QueryMultiple and then "there is only one" just causes confusion

Comment: *output is kinda long* - we don't need all million rows, just something adequately representative. For example "I have this sproc that runs 3 queries <insert a sample sproc that shows 3 short select statements>. In SSMS it produces these 3 result sets <show 3 result sets of 2 rows each>. I run it in c# like this <show c# code>. I want to get a single list of XYZ objects that looks like this <show some pseudoJson/list initializer representation of what you want>"

Comment: @CaiusJard these are all true, even tho I tried to make it as clear as possible that I think I did since I got my solution. I'll keep these in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a class as `DataModel` to relay your data from DB.

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string Values { get; set; }
}
```

Then use lambda `Groupby`

```
IEnumerable<Something> something = results.Read<DataModel>()
   .GroupBy(x=> x.Name)
  .Select(x=> new Something(){
     Name = x.Key,
     Values = x.Select(y=>y.Values)
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something exactly like this!